# Asserting mock created using spec has been called raises error

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I want to create a mock using `create_autospec` from the `unittest.mock` module and then assert that the mock has been called. From reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#create-autospec) I gathered that you can mock an instance of a class by passing the class object as a `spec` to `create_autospec` and setting the `instance` parameter to `True`.

When I call the created mock and then try to assert that my mock has been called I get two errors (second error caused by first one):

1. `TypeError: missing a required argument: 'self'`
2. `AssertionError: expected call not found.`

I expected my code to not raise any errors because the created mock should behave as an instance of a callable class and the mock was called.

Can someone explain to me why this error happens and what the correct way to do this is?

Here is a code snippet that recreates my issue:

```
from unittest.mock import create_autospec


class Thing:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


thing_mock = create_autospec(Thing, instance=True)
thing_mock()
thing_mock.assert_called_once_with()
```